# How to use unique pointer vector?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I use `vector<unique_ptr<Data>>` to store my data for its automatic memory  management and low cost of `unique_ptr`. I have a function to try to add new created data into it. The data may be really added or not. It it is added, I don't need to care about its memory deletion because the pointer vector will take care of it. If it is not added, I hope the new created data can be deleted automatically. Any simple way to implement it? The function may look like below or other similar forms. Thanks.

```
// Return true if really added, return flase if not.
bool add(vector<unique_ptr<Data>>& vec, Data* newData);
```

Based on Dave's answer, is `bool add(vector<unique_ptr<Data>>& vec, std::unique_ptr<Data>& newData)` better since `unique_ptr` non public copyable? Here a reference is used in the 2nd argument.

Comment: You want a vector that behaves like a set? What have you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accept `newData` as a `unique_ptr` too.

```
bool add(vector<unique_ptr<Data>>& vec, std::unique_ptr<Data> newData)
{
    if(blah blah blah)
    {
        vec.push_back(std::move(newData));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is this better `bool add(vector<unique_ptr<Data>>& vec, std::unique_ptr<Data>& newData)`? A reference is used in the 2nd argument.

Comment: @user1899020 Maybe, depends on the behavior you want. Do you want the caller of `add` to still have a valid `newData` if `add` doesn't add it? If so, a reference is desirable. If you want `newData` to die whether `add` adds it or not, accept it by value like is done above.

Comment: So use your function this way `add(vec, std::unique_ptr<Data>(new Data))`, right? Or any simpler syntax?

Comment: @user1899020 You got it. But you could make the `unique_ptr` anywhere before calling `add` and then call `add(vec, std::move(myPtr));`. It just depends on what makes sense for your particular structuring where you call `add`.

Comment: @user1899020: If you make the parameter a (non-const) reference, you are mandating that the object exist as a nameable l-value.  So you can't pass in temporaries, like the return value of a function.  But if you take it in by value, you can accept temporaries, and you still can take l-values as long as you move them.

Answer (score -1):

What are the semantics you want to achieve.

FWIW: a vector of unique_ptr is rarely a good idea.  *If* you
want the vector to have exclusive ownership, you're better off
using Boost's pointer vector.

Comment: Yeah I second user1899020. I fail to see the rationale in that statement. Containers of `unique_ptr`s are very common...

Comment: @user1899020 For the same reason you didn't want `auto_ptr` in a container (and the standard banned it): it's too easy to accidentally copy the value returned from the container.  (Or move it out of the container, which comes to the same thing.)  `std::iterator_traits<>::value_type` is there for a reason.  As far as I can tell, there's not even a guarantee that functions in `<algorithm>` never make a copy of the element.