# Compilation error enumerating vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, smart-pointers

```
void Test()
{
    vector< unique_ptr<char[]>> v;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        char* p = new char[10];
        sprintf_s(p, 10, "string %d", i);
        v.push_back( unique_ptr<char[]>(p) );
    }

    for(auto s : v)                // error is here
    {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

`error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`

Comment: I don't think you can copy a unique pointer. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758375/how-to-use-unique-pointer-vector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`unique_ptr` is non-copyable. You should use a reference to `const` in your range-based for loop. Moreover, there is no overload of `operator <<` for `unique_ptr`, and `unique_ptr` is not implicitly convertible to the underlying pointer type:

```
for(auto const& s : v)
//       ^^^^^^
{
    cout << s.get() << endl;
//          ^^^^^^^            
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why is `operator <<` not overloaded for `unique_ptr`? It is overloaded for `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Andy Prowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl) [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is not copyable (from the linked reference page):

> unique_ptr is neither copyable nor copy-assignable

The code could avoid using `unique_ptr` completely and just use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead:

```
void Test()
{
    std::vector< std::string > v;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back( std::string("string ") + std::to_string(i) );
    }

    for(auto& s : v)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```